# Converting from Caffe to Tensorflow: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, caffe

I am trying to convert the pre-trained caffe model provided [here](https://github.com/richzhang/colorization) into tensorflow [this converter](https://github.com/ethereon/caffe-tensorflow), which seems to be the most popular option out there. Nevertheless, when I run their script

```
$ python3 convert.py ../colorful-colorization/models/colorization_deploy_v2.prototxt --caffemodel ../colorful-colorization/models/colorization_release_v2.caffemodel --code-output-path ./out-code/mynet.py
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convert.py", line 60, in <module>
    main()
  File "convert.py", line 56, in main
    args.phase)
  File "convert.py", line 27, in convert
    transformer = TensorFlowTransformer(def_path, caffemodel_path, phase=phase)
  File "/home/ebalda/Documents/Python/playground/caffe2tensorflow/kaffe/tensorflow/transformer.py", line 221, in __init__
    self.load(def_path, data_path, phase)
  File "/home/ebalda/Documents/Python/playground/caffe2tensorflow/kaffe/tensorflow/transformer.py", line 227, in load
    graph = GraphBuilder(def_path, phase).build()
  File "/home/ebalda/Documents/Python/playground/caffe2tensorflow/kaffe/graph.py", line 140, in __init__
    self.load()
  File "/home/ebalda/Documents/Python/playground/caffe2tensorflow/kaffe/graph.py", line 146, in load
    text_format.Merge(def_file.read(), self.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 521, in Merge
    text.split('\n'),
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

After browsing around in github and stackoverflow, I could not find other persons having a similar issue. Does anyone know what could be the problem?